# How did/would you analyze OSX-Crisis

Tags: malware, ida, osx

I was taking a look at the OSX-Crisis sample obtained from [this site](http://contagiodump.blogspot.in/2012/12/aug-2012-w32crisis-and-osxcrisis-jar.html#more) and trying to analyze it for fun and learning. Choosing to disassemble as a Mac binary causes the start function to be discovered wrongly and hence affect the rest of the disassembly. I was reading the analysis of the malware [here](http://www.symantec.com/content/en/us/enterprise/media/security_response/whitepapers/crisis_the_advanced_malware.pdf), and am curious about how I can go about finding the correct entry point address.

I believe it can be figured out using the `LC_UNIXTHREAD` command eip value. In this case, should my approach be to disassemble the file within IDA as a "binary"(rather than a mach-o binary), navigate to 0x409c and press "C" ?

Comment: had a look at [this](http://reverse.put.as/2012/08/06/tales-from-crisis-chapter-1-the-droppers-box-of-tricks/) ?

Answer (score 3):

According to fG!'s [blog](http://reverse.put.as/2012/08/06/tales-from-crisis-chapter-1-the-droppers-box-of-tricks/) entry on OSX-Crisis (recommended read), the true EntryPoint is located in the segment `__INIT_STUB`, with code execution permission.